# Adding new row to a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datatable, devexpress

I have a GeidView in my form and I have a button which add new records to the GridView by adding a row to a Datatable and then make this DataTable as the GridContol's Data Source.

The problem is when I add a new record it display in the GridView but when I add another rocord it doesn't display in the GridView, The GridView always contains the first row I added to the DataTable !

So please could you help me to solve this problem ?

This is the source code :

```
private DataTable recompensesTable;

private void AjoutLivre_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          recompensesTable = MakeRecomponsesTable();
          recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;
        }
private DataTable MakeRecomponsesTable()
        {
            DataTable recmpensesTable = new DataTable("Recompenses");

            var anneeColumn = new DataColumn();
            anneeColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            anneeColumn.ColumnName = "Année";
            recmpensesTable.Columns.Add(anneeColumn);

            var prixLiteraireColumn = new DataColumn();
            prixLiteraireColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            prixLiteraireColumn.ColumnName = "Prix Litéraire";
            recmpensesTable.Columns.Add(prixLiteraireColumn);

            return recmpensesTable;
        }

private void nouveauRecompense_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow row = recompensesTable.NewRow();

            row[0] = ajoutRecompense.KeyWordAnnee;
            row[1] = ajoutRecompense.KeyWordPrixLiteraire;
            recompensesTable.Rows.Add(row);

            recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Page_Load you have `recompensesTable = MakeRecomponsesTable();`. That overwrites the changes and recreate the datatable values

On page postback, variables are restored to their default values and they need to be recreated. You can use Session to maintain your values

```
private void AjoutLivre_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
     DataTable recompensesTable = MakeRecomponsesTable();
     Session["recompensesTable"] = recompensesTable; //Save it to session the first time
     recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;
   }
}
```

and retrieve the session preserved value

```
private void nouveauRecompense_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable recompensesTable = (DataTable) Session["recompensesTable"]; //retrieve it from session
    DataRow row =  recompensesTable.NewRow();

    row[0] = ajoutRecompense.KeyWordAnnee;
    row[1] = ajoutRecompense.KeyWordPrixLiteraire;
    recompensesTable.Rows.Add(row);

    Session["recompensesTable"] = recompensesTable; //save it back to session

    recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;
}
```

Comment: :: +1 For great explanation. :)

Comment: I think the is for Asp.Net isn't it ? 'cuz I'm working on a WinForm application

Comment: winforms does not use gridview. It is called DataGridView. You should have indicated in your question. Add relevant information next time

Comment: in your `_click` event add `recompenseGridControl.DataBind()` after `recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;` and see how it goes

Comment: 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind'

Comment: Next time include all the relevant information if you really need to be helped. Half information makes people guess and turn potential answers away

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
private void AjoutLivre_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      recompensesTable = MakeRecomponsesTable();
      recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;
    }
```

To

```
private void AjoutLivre_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(!IsPostback)
         recompensesTable = MakeRecomponsesTable();
      recompenseGridControl.DataSource = recompensesTable;
    }
```

You also must save the datatable to session

Comment: I think the is for Asp.Net isn't it ? 'cuz I'm working on a WinForm application

Comment: Yes.. but GeidView  is available only in asp.net not in winforms.. Did you mean DataGeidView ?

Comment: If so. just add the `recompenseGridControl.DataBind()` After specifyind the data source if the control in `nouveauRecompense_Click` event

Comment: 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind'

Comment: Then you should specify the tags correctly in the question, That will help us to give you any solution.

Answer (score -1):

the recmpensesTable is always a new DateTable, you should save it to session for next use.